# Display dialog box on top right corner in android activity

Tags: android, android-layout

How to Display dialog box in the top right corner in android activity.

Below is my code for dialog box

item.xml

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.CustomToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="@string/off_txt"
        android:textOn="@string/on_txt" />

</TableLayout>
```

ActivityMy.java

```
 dialog_box = new Dialog(ActivityMy.this);
                        dialog_box.setContentView(R.layout.item);
                        dialog_box.show();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Do like this -**

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

wlp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want give some margin then use**

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
wlp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
wlp.y=100   //if you want give margin from top
wlp.x=100     //if you want give margin from left
wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
```